# Indexing Tables in Sequelizejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to use sequelizejs `sequelize.sync()` to index tables without relying on migrations?

If it not, is there any possible way to get migration going programatically with `sequelize`, it appears that the details suggested in the documentations [here](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/migrations) are actually deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have worked out a fairly acceptable way to do this.

I first install sequelize-cli in my project

```
npm install sequelize-cli --save
```

then, within the startup script, I have something that looks like this

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec
exec(__dirname + "/../node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate --config " + __dirname + "/config/config.json --migrations-path " + __dirname + "/migrations --models-path " + __dirname + "/models", function(err){
     // more code comes here
});
```

probably not the best way, but it works :)